# Conditional property name in typesript interface depending on passed in type

Tags: typescript

The title sound confusing but here's the gist of it.

I have a `User` interface that may or may not have some properties depending on from where it's fetched. Here's what I mean: (notice the optional properties `role` and `client_details`)

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;

  // -- One of these in undefined depending on fetch location
  role?: Role;
  client_details?: ClientDetails;
}
```

The previous approach works, however having an undefined value every time doesn't look very pretty. It would be neeter if I could do this:

```
export interface User<ExtraType = Role | ClientDetails> {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;

  // -- Dynamic property name instead, much cleaner approach
  [ExtraType === Role ? 'role' : 'client_details']: ExtraType;
}
```

This doesn't work and gives a bunch of errors, mainly `A computed property name cannot reference a type parameter from its containing type`.

I'm aware I can simply make a static property `extra` & simply use it every time, but I wanted the property name to somewhat make sense. Is this feasible at all? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a disjoint union of types. In your case, it can be done like this:

```js
interface UserBase {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
}
interface UserWithRole extends UserBase {
  role: Role;
  client_details?: undefined;
}
interface UserWithDetails extends UserBase {
  client_details: ClientDetails;
  role?: undefined;
}

export type User = UserWithRole | UserWithDetails;
```

Now whereever you have a value of type `User`, you can check it like this:

```js
function test(user: User) {
  if (user.role) {
    // here typescript knows that user is of type UserWithRole
  } else {
    // and here it knows that user is of type UserWithDetails
  }
}
```

I've added a declaration of missing property (`property?: undefined`) to both the types so typescript will not complain that `User` does not always have `.role` property; you can remove it and see the error in the `if (user.role)` line.

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECsFcGcBdQGYHsBOoAqBlUsmgHZLwDGSAtgA4A2AhgJb6g0BGSk8Zd00DA5jgE8KAU2gAoWEOGgASkirSAvKADeKecIByNMsIBcoOCj4BfANwSpoAMJU6w-LAAiw2PSrRQylQBNX7g3xIMmZhFHMxMQZYMIQaYmkAVWgwgCEaFNUxUFA6HwMjPgschDoUOAB9fB19Q1hjfF5i0FpK6t0C%20qLs0GEyALqGprETKMdY%20KSUlAB1OlgACzkFXoAPGPwfT2S0jOkVHvUFA2XhZuI7B1gKvzc6DwB%20A0hN4VL8YR8LUeiJhNAdrN5gsXHcPGsNlsAdN0pkDjkLvZHDd-PdoAZbEjnKiPM0jsInqAXn53p9vpFhKsKKh4JIRNCwl4GUDFqdQAAfZlzRag9zQCxiBAvYiwOhIRgxOAAChgYQMgIAlFkcnQEKAZdMAHT4pXwnKgECgBZhaR00TEYwUeAAa0IAHdPIsaPBZWguKAkGqzVzgacegjxdANJqqEheBqwtrg-jtLoFc0A-ggwoQ2GIyhNYiriiwdBNbd3PGeiZeh59v6DWAaJsjSbcjb7Y6Fs6idNcp5PYJ6YDuSCceJ9aBSEng6Hw66oymYzUi4Ph8nhKnx1qs8iC2j8zjZ6BRiYgA) the complete example